# Jacoco Error when running mvn install from command line

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to install local the jacoco project by typing mvn install / mvn compile. As you can see in my screenshot below I'm getting the error Build Failure. I suspect the maven or the java version might be the error.

[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce (enforce) @ org.jacoco.build ---
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
Detected Maven Version: 3.8.2 is not in the allowed range [3.3.9,3.8.2),(3.8.2,).
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[INFO] JaCoCo ..............................................FAILURE [  0.251 s]
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Core ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Report ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Agent RT ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Agent .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Ant ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Command Line Interface ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Examples ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Maven Plugin ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Tests .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Core ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Core :: Validation ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Core :: Validation Java 5 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Core :: Validation Kotlin ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Core :: Validation Java 7 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Core :: Validation Java 8 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Core :: Validation Groovy ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Core :: Validation Scala ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Report ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Agent RT ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Agent ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Ant .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Command Line Interface ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Examples ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Test :: Maven Plugin ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Documentation ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JaCoCo :: Distribution ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] root ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.423 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-11-08T18:38:42+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce (enforce) on project org.jacoco.build: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Please put the text of the error in your question, not a screenshot.

Comment: And looking at the error message *it tells you exactly what is wrong*.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  Include the full error message and folks can point to how it informs the issue.

Comment: @vsfDawg I have pasted the error message

Comment: You only pasted part of one line from the output.  See previous comments regarding images.  Replace the image link with the all of the text captured in that image.

Comment: @vsfDawg now I think it's better.

Comment: Better.. .but you missed a few lines above it tagged with WARNING.  Hint: The first line that is tagged with ERROR includes the phrase: _"Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed."_  This is referring to the omitted WARNING entry which describes the issue you are having.

Comment: @vsfDawg now is it OK ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states:

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce
> (enforce) on project org.jacoco.build: Some Enforcer rules have
> failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule
> failed.

The top of the provided output includes the following:

> [WARNING] Rule 1:
> org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with
> message: Detected Maven Version: 3.8.2 is not in the allowed range
> [3.3.9,3.8.2),(3.8.2,)

Therefore, it appears that your Maven version `3.8.2` is not in the allowed range of `[3.3.9,3.8.2)`.  Note that the notation `[3.3.9,3.8.2)` indicates that the allowed range starts with 3.3.9  and ends *before* 3.8.2 because the `[` indicates the value is included while the `)` indicates the ending value is excluded.

I assume you could resolve this by updating the JaCoCo to a version that is compatible with Maven 3.8.2, or using an earlier version of Maven.  The latter may introduce other compatibility problems so you should probably explore the former first.

Comment: Thank you. How can I update the JaCoCo to a version that is compatible with Maven 3.8.2 ?